# Why is the output for this code in this way?

Tags: java

```
class MainDemo{ 

     public static void main(String args[]){ 
        float arrayOne[] = {1, 2, 3, 4,5}; 
        for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) 
        { 
               arrayOne[iIndex] = iIndex; 
               iIndex=iIndex+1; 
         } 
         for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) 
         { 
               System.out.println(arrayOne[iIndex]); 
         } 
 } 
}
```

Why is the output?

```
0.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
```

instead of

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

because youre only replacing indexes 0 2 and 4 in the original array and leaving 1 and 3 untouched (iIndex is incremented by 2 each loop iteration)

Answer (score 2):

Because increment has been done twice:

```
 for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++)  
 /* Forloop itself increments iIndex*/
```

and

```
 iIndex=iIndex+1; 
 /*You are manually incrementing iIndex*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Dude because  when you start your first loop then it change the value of index 0,2 and 4 whose  previous values are 1,3 and 5 respectively and for these index new value after loop are 0,2 and 4 respectively thats why you get the output

```
0.0
2.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
```

instead of

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are updating only 0,2 and 4th index of array. As `iIndex` is updated twice once in loop in once if for statement
Original array

```
float arrayOne[] = {1, 2, 3, 4,5};
```

Updated array

```
   float arrayOne[] = {0, 2, 2, 4,4};
                       |_____|____|______ Are updated
```

Remove

```
iIndex=iIndex+1;
```

If you want to update every value.

Comment: Wow lots of activity on this question -- people are editing/answering at furious pace :) +1 for the ascii art highlighting the problem!

Answer (score 1):

In your first loop:

```
for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) //<-- here
{ 
      arrayOne[iIndex] = iIndex; 
      iIndex=iIndex+1; //<-- here - get rid of this
}
```

You add to `iIndex` twice. I've made notes above.

Get rid of the second one as you already increment `iIndex` as part of your for loop definition.

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse of this line  `iIndex=iIndex+1;` .

```
for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) //iIndex get incremented by 1 here.
    { 
           arrayOne[iIndex] = iIndex; 
           iIndex=iIndex+1; //iIndex get incremented by 1 here.
     }
```

The above loop will start from 0 and get incremented by 2 each time as mentioned above. So  iIndex values will be 0,2,4... .Value at index 1,3... remains unchanged and values at 0,2,4... get replaced by iIndex value.

Comment: please elaborate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 
            float arrayOne[] = {1, 2, 3, 4,5}; 
            for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) 
            { 
                   arrayOne[iIndex] = iIndex; 
                  // iIndex=iIndex+1; comment this line, twice increment is not required. 
             } 
             for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<arrayOne.length; iIndex++) 
             { 
                   System.out.println(arrayOne[iIndex]); 
             } 
     }
```